# Beth's theorem through Robinson Lemma

Tags: logic, model-theory, meta-math

I found this exercise (5.6.1) in "Introduction to model theory and to the metamathematics of algebra" of Abraham Robinson

[image]

with

[image]

and

[image]

Can someone help me to solve it or, alternately, give me a reference where it is solved?

Comment: You can see J.Shoenfield, [Mathematical Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=Vl1ZDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover) : **Definability Theorem** (Beth), page 81.